# how to cross-compile windows linux macos ubejar for javafx with deps.edn aliases?

Tags: javafx, clojure, uberjar, deps-edn

- Nightcode has this implemented
- https://github.com/oakes/Nightcode/blob/2e112c59cddc5fdec96059a08912c73b880f9ae8/deps.edn#L20
- but for some reason it does not work just by copying code

```clj
; does not work
{:paths ["./src" "out/ui" "out/identicon"]
 :mvn/repos {"jitpack.io" {:url "https://jitpack.io"}}
 :deps {org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.10.3"}
        org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.11.4"}
        org.clojure/core.async {:mvn/version "1.3.618"}

        test.check/test.check {:git/url "https://github.com/clojure/test.check"
                               :sha "b6a318af92e836f1f20960f38a5944168b88d60d"}
        cheshire/cheshire {:mvn/version "5.10.2"}

        cljfx/cljfx {:git/url "https://github.com/cljfx/cljfx"
                     :sha "29aaef956b22cee774524912a3083ed651033f1b"
                     :exclusions [org.openjfx/javafx-controls
                                  org.openjfx/javafx-base
                                  org.openjfx/javafx-fxml
                                  org.openjfx/javafx-graphics
                                  org.openjfx/javafx-media
                                  org.openjfx/javafx-web]}

        org.openjfx/javafx-base {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
        org.openjfx/javafx-fxml {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
        #_org.openjfx/javafx-graphics #_{:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
        #_org.openjfx/javafx-web #_{:mvn/version "17.0.2"}}

 :aliases
 {:Ripley {:extra-deps {Ripley/Ripley {:git/url "https://github.com/Empire-Strikes-Back/Ripley"
                                       :sha "becd2573ab55d42933134d346bc46cdd8fa08c04"}}}

  :Genie {:extra-deps {Genie/Genie {:git/url "https://github.com/Empire-Strikes-Back/Genie"
                                    :sha "fe9200d223e3a5c79e88dfa17bc2697c09dae70e"}}}

  :Zazu {:extra-deps {Zazu/Zazu {:git/url "https://github.com/Empire-Strikes-Back/Zazu"
                                 :sha "063ef7649c01284be8f5a1e9814d5bf83025ad76"}}}

  :shadow {:extra-deps {thheller/shadow-cljs {:mvn/version "2.18.0"}
                        nrepl/nrepl {:mvn/version "0.8.3"}
                        cider/cider-nrepl {:mvn/version "0.25.5"}
                        cider/piggieback {:mvn/version "0.5.2"}}}

  :ui {:extra-deps {reagent/reagent {:mvn/version "1.1.1"}
                    sci/sci {:git/url "https://github.com/borkdude/sci"
                             :sha "6c10e494371a37a56bef45c8148435888bae3a45"}}}

  :linux {:extra-deps {org.openjfx/javafx-base$linux {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
                       org.openjfx/javafx-fxml {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
                       org.openjfx/javafx-graphics$linux {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
                       org.openjfx/javafx-web$linux {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}}}
  :windows {:extra-deps {org.openjfx/javafx-graphics$win {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
                         org.openjfx/javafx-web$win {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}}}
  :macos {:extra-deps {org.openjfx/javafx-graphics$mac {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
                       org.openjfx/javafx-web$mac {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}}}}}
```

- also there is this anwser https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/133

how to compile uberjars for each OS with its own classifier?

Comment: "does not work" - what does not work? please add the error/stack
trace/...

Comment: A discussion of the process to do this using Maven is in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing).  I do not know how to perform the equivalent task using a Clojure-based build tool.  However, much of the information in the Maven-based solution is generic to the process of creating an uber jar for a JavaFX application and is not really specific to a Maven setup.

Comment: I recommend that you read and understand the information in that answer and see if you can get it to apply to your situation (assuming you wish to continue creating an uber jar).

Comment: An uber jar that includes JavaFX classes is not a supported runtime configuration for JavaFX application deployment. For information on alternative packaging solutions, e.g. jlink and jpackage, or a zip file containing separate module jars plus a shell script, see the [packaging section in the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).

Answer (score 0):

- answer found

  - program - Cara-Dune  - who assembles the uberjar - uses Genie library for it
  - he is essentially clojure/tools.build but can be run with clojure -X
  - now we can see that tools.build added such api and describes in doc it can also run with clojure -X = but Genie appeared before
  - say program runs clojure -X:windows:Genie Genie.core/process - this invokes essentially clojure/build.tool compilation
  - https://github.com/clojure/tools.build/blob/a9d0804ce8014088a7388e762034e9013922cacb/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/build/tasks/create_basis.clj
  - which in tern invokes deps create-basis
  - but - the :alias we never passed to that function, we incorrectly put it to clojure -X invocation
  - should be instead

```bash
  OPERATING_SYSTEM=$1
  COMMIT_HASH=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
  COMMIT_COUNT=$(git rev-list --count HEAD)
  clojure \
    -J-Dcljfx.skip-javafx-initialization=true \
    -X:Genie Genie.core/process \
    :main-ns Cara-Dune.main \
    :filename "\"out/Cara-Dune-$COMMIT_COUNT-$COMMIT_HASH-$OPERATING_SYSTEM.jar\"" \
    :paths '["src" "out/ui" "out/identicon"]' \
    :create-basis-opts "{:aliases [:$OPERATING_SYSTEM]}"
```

- and still - linux .jar is 80.7mb
- windows 108 mac 112 - because they include javafx jar for linux - they run on linux when they shouldn't

Comment: https://github.com/move-me-to-ipfs-shipyard/Cara-Dune/blob/66ae6cc263ca3dfcaf85c395ac0c8a8b31bba1ba/program.sh#L37